# Hide/show buttons are not hiding my div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, show

I have 3 divs and 3 buttons. On page load there should be just the first div visible. On clicking buttons "step1", "step2", "step3" there should appear div1 div2 and div3. But the only one of them should be always visible, the rest must be hidden. I wrote the following code, but unfortunately the first div is always visibe, whatever I click. Why?
Divs:

```
<div class="videoDiv">
    <img src="/images/Karolina_GFX/play_button.png" class='videoImage'><br>
    <a href="#!"><div class='buttonImage'><p id="germanText">Geschäftspräsentation</p></div></a>
    <button class="changeVideoButton1">Step1</button>
    <button class="changeVideoButton2">Step2</button>
    <button class="changeVideoButton3">Step3</button>
</div>



<div class="videoDiv2">
    <img src="/images/Karolina_GFX/play_button.png" class='videoImage2'><br>
    <a href="#!"><div class='buttonImage'><p id="germanText">The Company</p></div></a>
    <button class="changeVideoButton1">Step1</button>
    <button class="changeVideoButton2">Step2</button>
    <button class="changeVideoButton3">Step3</button>
</div>


<div class="videoDiv3">
    <img src="/images/Karolina_GFX/play_button.png" class='videoImage3'><br>
    <a href="#!"><div class='buttonImage'><p id="germanText">was ist zu tun?</p></div></a>
    <button class="changeVideoButton1">Step1</button>
    <button class="changeVideoButton2">Step2</button>
    <button class="changeVideoButton3">Step3</button>
</div>
```

js:

```
<script>
    $(".videoDiv1.videoDiv2, .videoDiv3").hide();

      $(".changeVideoButton1").click(function(){
          $(".videoDiv2,.videoDiv3").hide();
          $(".videoDiv1").show();
    });

      $(".changeVideoButton2").click(function(){
          $(".videoDiv1,.videoDiv3").hide();
          $(".videoDiv2").show();
    });

      $(".changeVideoButton3").click(function(){
          $(".videoDiv1,.videoDiv2").hide();
          $(".videoDiv3").show();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
$(".videoDiv1").show();
```

to this:

```
$(".videoDiv").show();
```

Just remove the 1 from all `.videoDiv1`

Comment: Omg am I really that blind or stupid? I was sitting on this around 4 hours without success XD

Answer (score 3):

change the class of the first div

from

```
<div class="videoDiv">
```

to

```
<div class="videoDiv1">
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="videoDiv1">
 <img src="/images/Karolina_GFX/play_button.png" class='videoImage'><br>
 <a href="#!"><div class='buttonImage'><p id="germanText">Geschäftspräsentation</p></div></a>
</div>
<div class="videoDiv2">
 <img src="/images/Karolina_GFX/play_button.png" class='videoImage2'><br>
 <a href="#!">
  <div class='buttonImage'><p id="germanText">The Company</p></div></a>    
</div>
<div class="videoDiv3">
  <img src="/images/Karolina_GFX/play_button.png" class='videoImage3'><br>
 <a href="#!"><div class='buttonImage'>
   <p id="germanText">was ist zu tun?
   </p>
  </div>
    </a>
 </div>
 <button class="changeVideoButton1">Step1</button>
 <button class="changeVideoButton2">Step2</button>
 <button class="changeVideoButton3">Step3</button>


<script type="text/javascript">
 $(".videoDiv2, .videoDiv3").hide();

 $(".changeVideoButton1").click(function(){
    $(".videoDiv2, .videoDiv3").hide();
    $(".videoDiv1").show();
 });

 $(".changeVideoButton2").click(function(){
    $(".videoDiv1, .videoDiv3").hide();
    $(".videoDiv2").show();
 });

 $(".changeVideoButton3").click(function(){
   $(".videoDiv2, .videoDiv1").hide();
    $(".videoDiv3").show();
 });
</script>
```